# How to properly sort and update huge collection documents with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with more than 100000 documents, I need to get rankings of *n* recrods and also a total records ranking.

I've tried with:

```
db.lineuppointsrecord.aggregate(    
  [      { $sort : {totalpoints: -1, _id: 1} }    
  ] )
```

And:

```
db.lineuppointsrecord.find({},{totalpoints: true}).sort({totalpoints: -1, _id: 1})
```

However these both failed due to the huge memory demand, what's the correct way to do this?

**I do not only want to sort this but to add a field to every record named `rank` which will be the ranked reached by each record's `totalpoints` attribute**

Comment: Before commenting in general that this question is faily broad. (aside from a simple answer from the documentation). I must note that your account here is fairly light on "accepted answers" of late. Perhaps attend to the questions you have asked already first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the online docs pages:

**$sort and Memory Restrictions**

> The $sort stage has a limit of 100 megabytes of RAM. By default, if
>   the stage exceeds this limit, $sort will produce an error. To allow
>   for the handling of large datasets, set the allowDiskUse option to
>   true to enable $sort operations to write to temporary files. See the
>   allowDiskUse option in db.collection.aggregate() method and the
>   aggregate command for details.

Answer (score 2):

A memory limitation applies when no index can service the query. The answer, thus, is to ensure an index exists:

```
db.lineuppointsrecord.ensureIndex( { totalpoints: -1, _id: 1 } );
```

Note that if you have a $match stage you should include those predicates first in the compound index above.

See [aggregation and index in the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/#aggregation-pipeline-operators-and-performance).